# All of a sudden my account dissapeared?

Tags: support, status-completed

Like every morning I was going to check out skeptics, just to find out that my account wasn't recognized by the site, it worked on all other SE sites except  this one, when I looked as a guest I can see my old questions are posted as user5169 , I'm not sure what happened to my account, as far as I know I haven't violate any policy or anything, apparently I was able to create a new account with the same ID but is not linking any of my previous activity,  I don't have idea what could have caused this, any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong, the account was removed by mistake as far as I can tell so far. I'll talk to someone from SE to see what exactly happened and to undelete your account, but they are mostly in NY and just waking up.

Comment: ok, thank you for the follow up Fabian

Comment: Just popping in to let it be known that we at Stack Exchange have been notified of this event and are working to rectify it.

Comment: @rvs it was me, sorry about that :-/

Comment: @GraceNote thanks and sorry again

Comment: Thank you all for following up.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

We don't have a means to undelete a deleted user at the moment. But, since the majority of data is ultimately linked to all the content you have provided to the site, reversing this mistake was just a matter of reassociating all of your former posts to this new ID that you have created. Which has already been done (and you can thank [Nick Craver](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/3/nick-craver) for accomplishing the deed).

Comment: Thank you both you,I think I lost a few badges ( I don't remember exactly) but other than that everything looks good, thank you very much for working on getting this fixed.

Comment: @rvs Ooh, yeah, I can think of a couple badges that would've been lost (announcer series, and perhaps more issue-y the Fanatic badge). Unfortunately, I don't think we can dig up what badges your old account had to shift them over, I'm sorry.

Comment: that's ok Grace I can live with it and I appreciate the efforts from you and Nick, thanks again.